# How do objects give kinetic energy to another object while exerting a reaction force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

According to newton's third law, if an object exerts a force on another object, then that object exerts an equal and opposite force on the initial object. But where does the kinetic energy required for the initial object to move backwards come from?

Comment: It comes from the force acting over a finite distance. You may have heard of the work-kinetic-energy theorem... The work done by the external force is equal to the change in kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

What do those Newton third law pair of forces do?
Each of them causes a deformation of one or other of the objects.
So the force on object 1 due to object 2 compresses object 1 and the force on object 2 due to object 1 compresses object 2 as though they were springs.
So now you have "spring/elastic" energy stored in the system at the expense of the initial kinetic energy.
In trying to return to their original shape further forces are exerted between the two objects as the springs relax and at the same time (some of) the "spring/elastic" energy is returned as kinetic energy.
The net effect is a transfer of momentum and kinetic energy between the two colliding objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is the object's own (initial) kinetic energy.

The second objects provides a force against the first which decelerates it, changing (and potentially reversing) the velocity. The second object feels a force of this same magnitude, but in the opposite direction; it therefore accelerates in this opposite direction. The force is the reaction force. What determines the extend of deceleration (reaction force) which occurs, I don't know, since there can be a range of final velocities for both objects which conserve linear momentum (a basic conservation law). Because the reaction force is the same magnitude on both objects, their accelerations (=>final change in velocity) are in proportion to their masses. The change is also often assumed to be instantaneous, although in an extended object which is elastic it would happen over a span of time.

If it is a completely elastic collision, total kinetic energy is conserved, meaning the accelerations occur in such a way that the final velocities preserve the original kinetic energy. That would provide a unique solution not the problem, I think, and unique final velocities. In this case, none of the energy is lost as heat (and this means the particles cannot deform inelastically when they meet).

If the collision is completely inelastic, such as when one object becomes embedded in another, total kinetic energy is not conserved. The two will move off more slowly, keeping the same total momentum as the initial body had, but this does not mean that they have same kinetic energy as the original. This can be found by looking at the kinetic energy formula, which goes with v-squared, while momentum goes with v. In this case, the energy has to be lost as heat, maybe dissipated when the objects deform.

What determines to what extent the collision will be elastic or inelastic I don't know. Given this constraint, we then either only make sure the momenta add up correctly, or make sure that both the momenta and kinetic energies before and after add up correctly.

Also, these two situations seem special as seen from the center of mass frame of the system. Specifically, in that frame the kinetic energy completely disappears in the case that the bodies coalesce, and the initial velocities completely reverse in the case that they do not.